# Conditionally do jsonb_array_elements

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column called `info` that some type have the form of an object: `{ id: 2 }`

and some other types it has the shape of an array: `[{ id: 2 }]`

I have a query that does this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(users.info)
```

Now, if my data set has just arrays in the `info` column, there is no issue, but if there is one that is not an array, but rather an object, I get the error:

`ERROR:  cannot extract elements from an object`

Is there a way in PostgreSQL for that CROSS JOIN LATERAL to ignore the rows that are not arrays in the `info` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_typeof()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to eliminate rows with non-array jsonb column:

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from users
    where jsonb_typeof(info) = 'array'
    ) s
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(info);
```

[Working example in rextester.](https://rextester.com/PJCGW41689)